# Google Adsense Do not show the ads on my website page

Tags: php, json, wordpress, magento, google-advertising-id

I have set up the my website url for google ads on Google Adsense Account  but there is not display the advertisement on my website page. So, Pls help me on it

Comment: Did you add code to you website in order to display ads?

Answer (score 1):

Adsense is not working with some scripts in Wordpress. I sugest you reading [this article](http://www.indexofapps.com/solved-google-adsense-does-not-appear-in-some-wordpress-themes/)

Download template there or use your own.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible reasons:

1. If you have set up the adsense account and has not been fully reviewed. This may take even up to 72hrs.
2. You might have violated the adsense policies, thus the ads will not display.
3. You might have suppressed the ad spaces where you have pasted your ad codes.

Comment: We have done this thing on my website but still we didn't get the proper solution on that and didn't display the google ads from google adsense account on my website. So, Please give me other solution on that.